# Is it possible to run the app , when ever user gets call?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Actual Requirement is, My app has to show some kind of alert when ever  user gets the call from a particular number.

I don't know whether it is possible or not , Please help me.

Is it possible to run the app , when ever user gets call?

Answer (score 7):

No, it's not possible. And neither can you access the user's call log at a later time.

Answer (score 5):

No it's not. There's no such notification.